# Rails switch from translated URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rails-i18n, globalize

I have configured I18n, Globalize and FriendlyId in a Multilingual Rails Application.
Moreover, I pretend to translate url according locale.

> For example:

```
http://localhost:3000/es/micontroller/mi-casa   
http://localhost:3000/en/mycontroller/my-house
```

Those urls already exists, the translation works as expected.

> These are the language switcher links I have added:

```
= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :es, "Español", locale: :es  
= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :en, "English", locale: :en
```

My issue is that when I switch languages, the url only changes the locale parameter, instead of changing slug.

> For example, toggling from English to Spanish results in something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/es/mycontroller/my-house
```

PD: Is a good practice what I pretend to do with my urls? I have searched some time with no results.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide full specs of your problem, so I came up with implementation of my own.

I've managed to accomplish kind of what you expect with addtional help of this gem:
https://github.com/norman/friendly_id-globalize

It also translates the slug column needed by the friendly_id. Without it, slug was taken directly from main model, not from translation.

Few snippets from my setup (I used Post as my model/scaffold):

```
# model
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend FriendlyId
  translates :title, :body, :slug
  friendly_id :title, use: :globalize
end

# routes
scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
  resources :posts
end

# migration
class CreatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :posts do |t|
      t.string :slug 
      # slug column needs to be both in normal and translations table
      # according to friendly_id-globalize docs
      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    Post.create_translation_table! title: :string, body: :text, slug: :string
  end

  def down
    drop_table :posts
    Post.drop_translation_table!
  end
end


# switcher in view
<%= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :en, "English", locale: :en %>
<%= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :es, "Español", locale: :es %>
```

I hope this will help. If not, please provide more details.

Comment: Thanks, your code has almost the same working settings I'm using. I will provide more details. The problem with the switcher is that it doesn't print the translated href for the not-current locale. For example, If I'm in English, the href from Spanish link will print the slug in English. So when I click it, my urls becomes something like: /es/my-english-slug, instead of /es/mi-slug-en-español

Comment: A solution I have found is to build the urls by myself, but I don't think it is a "Rails way" solution. I'm using globalize-accessors gem, it can print all translated slug versions in the same view, so I can print href like: /en/my-english and /es/mi-español.